# How do I achieve the proper output for this dataset?

Tags: python

I'm having an issue getting the proper output from my dataset.

I have a dataset that contains a Ticker Name, Weight, and Score and would like to pull a unique list of TIK, Weight, Score where the Score = MAX(score) for the given ticker symbol.

An example of the dataset would be

```
[(u'COOL ', 25, 452.50000000000006), (u'MIND', 25, 221), (u'SIMO', 25, 209), (u'RAVN', 25, 131.75), (u'AET', 25, 99), (u'SBUX', 25, 83.5), (u'ATVI', 25, 47.75), (u'CACI', 25, 45.5), (u'DISH ', 25, 17.25), (u'COOL ', 15, 271.5), (u'MIND', 15, 132.6), (u'SIMO', 15, 125.39999999999999), (u'RAVN', 15, 79.05), (u'AET', 15, 59.4), (u'SBUX', 15, 50.099999999999994), (u'ATVI', 15, 28.65), (u'CACI', 15, 27.3), (u'DISH ', 15, 10.35), (u'COOL ', 10, 181), (u'MIND', 10, 88.4), (u'SIMO', 10, 83.6), (u'RAVN', 10, 52.699999999999996), (u'AET', 10, 39.6), (u'SBUX', 10, 33.4), (u'ATVI', 10, 19.099999999999998), (u'CACI', 10, 18.2), (u'DISH ', 10, 6.8999999999999995), (u'COOL ', 5, 90.5), (u'MIND', 5, 44.2), (u'SIMO', 5, 41.8), (u'RAVN', 5, 26.349999999999998), (u'AET', 5, 19.8), (u'SBUX', 5, 16.7), (u'ATVI', 5, 9.549999999999999), (u'CACI', 5, 9.1), (u'DISH ', 5, 3.4499999999999997)]
```

.....for each ticker in the dataset.

And the result I am looking to achieve is:

```
COOL 25 452.50
MIND 15 132.6
SIMO 10 83.6
```

ex. AAPL has a weight of 25, TITN has a weight of 20, and ANF has a weight of 15 and its associated score at a weight of 15 until sum(weight) = 100.

Each ticker can only be reported once for a given weight. So if AAPL has the highest score at weight 25, it cannot be used again at any other weight.

This was tricky to explain hopefully I have provided enough for you guys to provide some guidance.

***appended some real sample data for additional clarity

Comment: is your output correct? because `300` is not the highest score between the `TITN` tickers

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> groups = groupby(table, lambda x: x[0])     # table not sorted because items already are
>>> [max(item[1], key=lambda x:x[2]) for item in groups]
[('AAPL', 25, 400), ('TITN', 25, 350), ('ANF', 25, 250)]
>>>
```

or in two lines (just for fun, sorry):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [max(item[1], key=lambda x:x[2]) for item in groupby(table, lambda x: x[0])]
[('AAPL', 25, 400), ('TITN', 25, 350), ('ANF', 25, 250)]
```

**Edit:** Taking into account the new table and the example given by the OP, I understand that the analysis has to be done giving preference to the valid max values available in the table at each step of selection. Then using:

```
table = [(u'COOL ', 25, 452.5), (u'MIND', 25, 221),
         (u'SIMO', 25, 209), (u'RAVN', 25, 131.75), (u'AET', 25, 99),
          .............................
         (u'CACI', 5, 9.1), (u'DISH ', 5, 3.45)]

while table:
    maxim = max(table, key= lambda x:x[2])
    print maxim
    table = [tup for tup in table if tup[1] != maxim[1] and tup[0] != maxim[0]]
```

this prints:

```
(u'COOL ', 25, 452.5)
(u'MIND', 15, 132.59999999999999)
(u'SIMO', 10, 83.599999999999994)
(u'RAVN', 5, 26.350000000000001)
```

Note that depending on the rule you follow for consecutively selecting your items the result is different (see my comment below). The condition selected in the code above is the one giving a result closer to that of the OP. It is possible that the additional term in my answer corresponds to an error in the OP example

Comment: much thanks joaquin, i will test this scenario on my real dataset and confirm it!

Comment: joaquin, is there an adjustment that can be done to return a unique weight per ticker?  Notice how all the tickers in your output have the same weight, this should decrement based on score. so AAPL has a weight of 25, TITN has a weight of 20, and ANF has a weight of 15

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean that 25 should be in only one of the tuples, then this would mean there is not a unique answer. If I get ('AAPL', 25, 400) first then none of the other two tuples would be part of the result. But if I select ('ANF', 25, 250) first, then ('AAPL', 25, 400) would not be in the result. Is that what you need ? Is there any other condition about how to select the results?

Comment: I think my dataset needed to be simplified.  There was no benefit to assigning every weight value to each symbol, it was actually complicating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without using some additional libraries this can be done as follows:

```
def get_element(lst, key):
  for obj in lst:
    if key(obj):
      return obj
  return None

def generate_list(data_set):
  result = []
  for obj in data_set:
    temp = get_element(result, lambda k: k[0] == obj[0])
    if temp is None:
      result.append(obj)
    elif obj[1] > temp[1]:
      ind = result.index(temp)
      result[ind] = obj      
  return result
```

which results in the same list format as your input.

Comment: Much thanks freakish! I will test this against my real data set.  Thanks for the approach without the use of libraries!

Answer (score 0):

Many valid answers. My answer focuses on readability for the developer:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Share = namedtuple('Share', 'name weight score')
d = {}
for share in [Share(*i) for i in table]:
    try:
        d[share.name] = share if share.score > d[share.name][2]\
                              else d[share.name]    
    except KeyError:
        d[share.name] = share

for share in d:
    print repr(d[share][:]).strip('()')

>>> 'AAPL', 25, 400
>>> 'TITN', 25, 350
>>> 'ANF', 25, 250
```

In your table it seems like the weight is already integrated in the score, because every weight point seems to represent 10 score points and there is a direct correlation between weight and score.

Comment: No real need for any calculation, just want to find a unique list of rows where the ticker with the highest score for a particular weight is chosen, and only used once per weight.  So there will be many tickers in the dataset, but i only want display the best for a particular weight.

Comment: the highest score for a tik & weight combination.  The end goal is to provide a list of stocks that are weighted by their score, and a stock can only be referenced once...so the 'highest scoring' stocks should be the ones associated to the highest weights.  Thanks for your help sir!

Comment: Don, it seems all tickers are returned with the same weight, can this be decremented based on score? so AAPL has a weight of 25, TITN has a weight of 20, and ANF has a weight of 15 and its associated score at a weight of 15?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the feedback!  I realized from your input i needed to take a step back in the process.

As oppose to assigning each weight to every ticker and trying to query that dataset, I assigned a unique weight to a ticker based on their overall score.

**This uses a dataset that is already ordered by top score.*

```
x = (25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5)
y = 0
for each in table:
    if y > 7:
        pass
    else:
        w = each[0], each[1], each[2], x[y]
        print w
        y += 1
```

Thanks for your guidance!  And for your troubles, these are some quality stocks...

```
(u'COOL ', 2.98, 0.54, 25)
(u'MIND', 23.96, 2.12, 20)
(u'SIMO', 22.35, 1.87, 15)
(u'RAVN', 65.35, 3.45, 10)
(u'AET', 43.93, 1.74, 10)
(u'SBUX', 47.6, 1.59, 10)
(u'ATVI', 12.56, 0.24, 5)
(u'CACI', 56.96, 1.04, 5)
```

Comment: you are not answering your own original question, instead you are answering a question that was never made !.

Comment: @joaquin looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @Kev you have the last word, but I could not imagine how one could derive the above answer from any of the two versions of the question and expected results posted by the OP (himself)...